# Looking for a book about talking dragons with no humans

Tags: story-identification, soft-sci-fi, dragons

When I was a kid I remember going to a relative's house and reading the beginning of a book about warring factions of Dragons. I was not able to finish before the weekend visit was over. I've never found that book and the relative is clueless. Here's what I can remember about the book: 
 
This book was about dragons at war with each other. They could speak and carry on dialog between each other. They had civilizations/societies. 
 There were at least two warring factions of dragons. I have no recollection as to wether they came from "the same" society, or completely different worlds, etc.

#### If my memory is right, there were no humans - it was only dragons!

And, if I remember correctly it was a series and this was the first book. 
The dragons on the dust cover were flying/fighting in air, one was dark/blue-ish and one was a red color. Very traditional as far as dragons were concerned, similar to GOT - they had distinct scales, not smooth-skin; very mean looking, very "pointy" - everything looked sharp. 
I can't confidently say whether they were Dragons or Wyverns. 
The dust cover was semi-new looking - to me that means it was likely printed in the 80s or after - but I have no idea if this was a "new" book, or a re-printed one. I would be speculating to say either way. If I had to guess I'd say it was from the later 80s/early 90s. 
I read parts of it c.1998-2000 in the US.
For some reason I feel like there was a "space" aspect as if the different factions were from "different planets" but I am less sure about this than anything else. (This is by far the least confident detail.)
It's been twenty years and I can't remember enough to track this thing down. I try to search every now and then but I never seem to find it.

#### Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like Wings of Fire, but the first book of that came out in 2012.  (There were humans, but they were relatively unimportant primitives.)  I'm not aware of anything that suggests WoF was derivative of an earlier work.

Comment: i get similar vibes too. its like wings of fire :)

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Answer (score 6):

[The Dragons at War](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/29173.The_Dragons_at_War), edited by Margaret Weis and Tracy Hickman, published in 1985 is an anthology of stories set in the Dragonlance Universe.

I can't find any indication that the stories do not feature humans, but the time period and cover seem to match your description.

> Dragons, the true children of Krynn, are power incarnate, and they
> know it. They come in all guises and forms. Their personalities are as
> varied as thier colors. Their magical abilities are virtually
> unlimited. And nothing is so terrifying as dragons on the wing.
>
> In this collection, a follow-up to the popular The Dragons of Krynn
> anthology, Dragonlance creators, Margaret Weis and Tracy Hickman serve
> up a fantastical array of dragon tales featuring the motley races of
> Krynn and the deadliest creatres of the Dragonlance saga.

[image]

Comment: If this is indeed set in the Dragonlance universe, there are definitely humans...

Answer (score 0):

It may be this book:

[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B0076Q1GE0](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0076Q1GE0)

There's a red and blue dragon fighting on the cover and it might not feature any humans. Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  This answer needs more details and content.  You should at least include the cover image in your answer so people don't need to follow the link to actually see your answer.  (Your answer should stand on its own without needing people to follow any links you include.)